# bazel build failing - pip_deps dying due to SigKill

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pytorch

I'm using ubuntu/focal64 on vagrant, and trying to get a bazel toolchain working for development.

I did pip3 install -r requirements.txt on my teams repo, and it seems to have successfully installed all the requirements. However I then run `bazel build /path/to/target:run` on some target, and get the following output:

```
... <More Packages Loaded here> ...
Collecting torch==1.7.1
 (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/f9910d98673307a31f928c448bd4acd0/external/rules_python/python/pip_install/extract_wheels/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/vagrant/.cache/bazel/_bazel_vagrant/f9910d98673307a31f928c448bd4acd0/external/rules_python/python/pip_install/extract_wheels/__init__.py", line 87, in main
    subprocess.run(pip_args, check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/vagrant/venv/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--isolated', 'wheel', '-r', '/home/vagrant/tech-backends/requirements.txt']' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>.
)
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package '@pip_deps//': rules_python_external failed: Collecting gremlinpython==3.4.6
  Using cached gremlinpython-3.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting aenum==2.2.3
  Using cached aenum-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
... <More Packages Loaded here> ...
```

This same pattern repeats about 4 times (as in has an error in the exact same spot), before finally showing a `FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)`.

Any ideas on what's going on here? Is there a problem with "torch"? (Since it dies there everytime). Note - I don't think there is an issue with "gremlinpython==3.4.6", I think the "rules_python_external_failed:..." line is missing a newline character.

Follow-up: I ran `python3 -m pip --isolated wheel torch==1.7.1` directly, and it gets killed:

```
Collecting torch==1.7.1
Killed
```

However, `pip3 install torch==1.7.1` works fine. Not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the root cause was, but I ended up downgrading my VM to ubuntu/bionic64 (it was on focal64), and switch to python 3.7+ (instead of 3.8+ which was on ubuntu/focal64). Things seem to be working now under the same CPU / Ram configs.